# After downloading Monterey with the intention of creating a usb-boot instead it is launched

Tags: macos, usb, startup

This looks good .. except it's not what was intended. I need a `usb boot` drive for a *different* sick macbookPro.

[image]

I can't find where this software was downloaded to on my drive. Any pointers where to look?

Comment: If the [posts on using createinstallmedia](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=createinstallmedia) don’t cover your specifics, please edit the post with some more details on what you seek or the roadblock faced. Lots of good information from Apple and here should be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always launches automatically. You can just quit it, same as any other app.

The file itself is in Applications/Install macOS [name].